# How to clear a "stuck" page transition in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, transition

I've got an app at present which has failed certification due to a page transition error.

The problem is very sensitive to timing, but can be reproduced by:

1. Start the app - wait for the home page to show
2. Navigate to a child page
3. As soon as the navigation starts, then hit the start button
4. Then hit the back button - the child page is there
5. Then hit the back button - the home page is not there - it's a blank screen

If I then hit the screen lock button, then unlock the phone, then the page appears normally.

There's no data reason that I can see why the home page is not shown, so it feels like this is something to do with the page transitions.

There are setup using:

```
        var navInTransition = new NavigationInTransition
        {
            Backward = new TurnstileTransition { Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.BackwardIn },
            Forward = new TurnstileTransition { Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.ForwardIn }
        };

        var navOutTransition = new NavigationOutTransition
        {
            Backward = new TurnstileTransition { Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.BackwardOut },
            Forward = new TurnstileTransition { Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.ForwardOut }
        };

        TransitionService.SetNavigationInTransition(this, navInTransition);
        TransitionService.SetNavigationOutTransition(this, navOutTransition);
```

If I remove this transition code, then my app never "gets stuck".

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Does anyone have any ideas how I can work out in code if the page transitions are stuck - and if they are how I might then be able to restart them?

Answer (score 1):

If this is on 256MB devices only it may be a memory related issue. Try disabling the use of transitions in this situation.
As recommended by http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Best_practice_tips_for_delivering_apps_to_Windows_Phone_with_256_MB

Alternatively you could try removing just one side of the animation. I've had transition issues in the past (sorry, can't remember the exact details) that were addressed by removing the `NavigationOutTransition`.

Comment: Thanks. This is on a full Lumia 800 device and seems to affect several apps... but the user has to press "Start" at the exact right moment. If I remove the NavigationOutTransition, then the user doesn't seem to see a transition at all...  I guess I'll log it on codeplex - there are a few other transition issues there - e.g. http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/8396